# Return digits from a string in bash shell

Tags: regex, string, bash

i'd like to return only the digits from a string variable in bash shell. For example, for:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="./file_02.txt"
file_num_tag=?????????????????
echo $file_num_tag
```

...i'd like to return

```
>>> 02
```

I know this is super trivial, but I'm confusing myself searching around for answers and I'd like to know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this BASH string replacement:

```
file="./file_02.txt"
echo "${file//[^[:digit:]]}"
02
```

`[^[:digit:]]` will match and remove all non-digits from your string `file`.

Or using `tr` (if not using BASH):

```
num=`echo "$file" | tr -cd '[[:digit:]]'`
```

Comment: And if you're on an ancient shell that doesn't support that kind of substitution: `echo "${file}" | tr -cd '0-9'`

Comment: Thanks, Yes that's right, let me add that also in answer.

Comment: @Jenny_Winters if this answer is exactly what you needed, then please *accept* it.

Comment: I will absolutely do that one the minimum time limit is up! Thanks for your suggestion!